# Updating posterior probability using new prior

Tags: probability

I live in a country where 0.1% of the population is infected by a virus.

There is a diagnostic test available that is positive 99% of the time when the patient does have the virus, and is positive 5% of the time when the patient does not have the virus.

I have gotten a positive result from this test, so the probability that I have the virus is around 1.9%, computed as follows:

$$P(v|+) = \frac{P(+|v)*P(v)}{P(+|v)*P(v) + P(+|v^c)*P(v^c)}$$

I take the same test a second time, and get back another positive result. What is now the probability that I have the virus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *exactly* a justifiable assumption—since realistically the results of repeated tests on a given patient *should* be positively correlated—but to *answer the question* you need to assume that the results of the test are *conditionally independent* for any given virus state.

So $\mathsf P(+_1,+_2\mid v)=\mathsf P(+_1\mid v)\cdot\mathsf P(+_2\mid v)\\ \mathsf P(+_1,+_2\mid v^\mathsf c)=\mathsf P(+_1\mid v^\mathsf c)\cdot\mathsf P(+_2\mid v^\mathsf c)$

Now find $\mathsf P(v\mid +_1,+_2)$ in the same manner as previously.

$\lower{10ex}\;$

---

$\tiny\text{Seriously, textbook authors, stop abusing the + symbol in this manner. $~$ It is most annoying.}$